# Javascript: How to subtotal values in list of { value, date } by time period?

Tags: javascript, list

I have a list of objects like this:

```
const rawData = [
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-24"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-24"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-27"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-27"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-11-16"
    }
]
```

I want to sum the quantities that belong in the same time period.
For instance, applying a monthly period, I would like to obtain a list like this:

dataTotalledByMonth:

```
[
    {
        "quantity": 176000,
        "period": "2017-10"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "period": "2017-11"
    }
]
```

I want to come up with a general solution that will allow me to switch to different periods (annually, weekly, quarterly, etc) and get the processed list dynamically.

Comment: And what have you come up with so far? You should add that code to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
const rawData = [
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-24"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-24"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-27"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-10-27"
    },
    {
        "quantity": 44000,
        "date": "2017-11-16"
    }
]

const calculateTotal = keyExtractor => data => 
Object.values(data.reduce((res, item) => {
   const date = keyExtractor(item)
   return {
     ...res, 
     [date]: {
       ...res[date],
       date,
       quantity: (res[date]?.quantity || 0) + item.quantity
     }
   }
}, {})) 

const annualCalculateTotal = calculateTotal(({date}) => date.substring(0, 4))
const monthlyCalculateTotal = calculateTotal(({date}) => date.substring(0, 7))

const afterAndBeforedateKeyGenerator = date => item => new Date(date) > new Date(item.date)? `before ${date}`: `after ${date}` 

console.log(annualCalculateTotal(rawData))
console.log(monthlyCalculateTotal(rawData))

console.log(calculateTotal(afterAndBeforedateKeyGenerator('2017-10-27'))(rawData))
```

Answer (score 0):

While @R4ncid's solution works, I have an idea for a simpler code, which I deem more easier to follow:

```js
const rawData = [{
    "quantity": 44000,
    "date": "2017-10-24"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 44000,
    "date": "2017-10-24"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 44000,
    "date": "2017-10-27"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 44000,
    "date": "2017-10-27"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 44000,
    "date": "2017-11-16"
  }
];

const final = {};

rawData.forEach(row => {
  // take just the first 2 date elements (year + month)
  const period = row.date.split('-').slice(0, -1).join('-');
  if (final[period]) {
    final[period].quantity += row.quantity;
  } else {
    final[period] = {
      period,
      quantity: row.quantity
    };

  }
});

console.log(final);
console.log(Object.values(final));
```

Comment: this works only id you want to group quantity by month

Comment: Right. But it's easy to figure out how to "fix" this. Also, your code doesn't account for dates like "2017-11-1", or "2017-1-1". You're assuming that there are leading zeros for the month and/or day, while with OP's code we don't have this information.

Comment: if you look at my solution you can notice that the way you implement the type of aggregation and tagging is based on `keyExtractor` function that you can define as you want